# Convert binary data to char[] in C

Tags: c

I have `void *data` in C which point to a binary data (image), and want to convert it to `char* new_data` to store somewhere else; then afterwards I want to convert `new_data` back to binary form.

The problem is, because of `data` contains many `0` in the middle, if I do

`(char*) data`

the new string will be truncated at the first `0`. My very first idea is to temporarily convert `0` to other value, but a new problem will appear.

What is a good way to perform my task?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "the new string will be truncated at the first `0`" Then, don't treat the data as string. Usage of `char*` is not limited to pointing at strings.

Comment: @MikeCAT Actually, use of `char*` _is_ limited to strings in practice. This is because `char` has implementation-defined signedness and therefore can't be reliably used for any other purpose than for holding strings. Instead, the OP should use `unsigned char` or preferably `uint8_t`.

Comment: What mean `char []` - ASCII encoding of binary (i.e. 09 -> 30 39 = '0' '9') or simply changing the type of pointer?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comment, but eventually what is the suggestion?

Comment: If it is image data it must be `unsigned` type. And don't use string handling functions, use `memcmp` and `memmove` and `memset` which BTW all take `void*` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should not treat your data as a string. You can see it as an array of bytes. For that, I suggest to use the type `uint8_t` defined in `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 0):

By assigning one pointer type to other doesn't change the data itself. It seems you are using string operation on your data which doesn't make sense. If you want to just copy data then use `memcopy` function. And if you want to manipulate your data then typecast it's start address as uint8_t*